# Text over icon (stacked on top of each other towards reader)

Tags: overlays, stack, icon

How to add text over icon (stacked on top of each other towards reader).

Basically LaTeX equivalent of that html question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644741/how-to-position-text-over-font-awesome-icon

and that answer:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-trophy fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="color:red;">
          <span style="font-size:35px; margin-top:-20px; display:block;">
              #1
          </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faIcon{trophy}\kern-7.25pt\relax
\raisebox{4.5pt}{\textcolor{white}{\tiny 1}}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Exactly, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use a `\stackinset`.  Here, the inset `1` is stacked .05pt to the right of and 1.7pt above center.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{.05pt}{c}{1.7pt}{\textcolor{white}{\tiny 1}}{\faIcon{trophy}}
\end{document}
```

[image]